# ldconfig rJava does not work

Tags: ld, rjava, rweka

I am working on an open source R package which requires rJava and RWeka and somehow the rJava and RWeka breaks **mysteriously** on my local machine.

1. Anyone knows why the rJava could break ?
2. It seems that the system could not find the shared object, so I did the follwing both:

   sudo ldconfig -l /home/sunxd/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rJava/libs/rJava.so

besides, I add `/home/sunxd/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rJava/libs/rJava.so` into `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `sudo ldconfig`

then I run `ldconfig -p | grep rJava`,  there is no return at all. Anyone knows why? Is it because rJava.so is broken so it did not appear in the cache? If so, how can I check is a .so file is broken ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `/home/sunxd/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rJava/libs` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, then run `sudo ldconfig`, then reboot your system.